# Configurations of Django application deployed on DigitalOcean

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a little trouble such as: I've created a Django application and deployed it on DigitalOcean via Nginx, Unicorn. Everything works very well with an IP address. But now I've bought a domain address and set it to my application. After this trouble has come. I can't open my admin dashboard on my computer, application is not opening on my phone, but opens on friend's phone, and so on. I just want to know, are my configurations right for replacing IP address with domain name ?

`settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['134.209.39.229','challengers.az']
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name challengers.az;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Configurations look sane, and I can report that your site loads in my browser when going to http://challengers.az, My guess is that you have a local network or configuration problem which is causing your headache.

Comment: @anowlinorbit solution was just in patience 